# Storm Door closer that allows over 90 degrees of opening

Tags: doors, storm-door, closer

Is there a type of Storm Door closer that allows the door to open over 90 degrees? In a lot of commercial spaces you’ll see those door closers with hinged folding 2 piece arms which allow an almost 180 degree range of motion (note: this is just an example, I’m not looking for anything with that extreme range of motion - just something that will go slightly beyond 90).

Does anything like that exist in a format designed to fit on a typical storm door.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something similar to this (Open > 90 degrees. 110 degrees this model).

[image] https://www.doorware.com/site/product.cfm?id=15335

Try this too. Though it indicates open 90 degrees, but actually it may open up further.

**Wright Products V150WH Heavy Duty Pneumatic Closer**
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for that link. I was worried that a commercial one wouldn’t be viable do to the typical space constraints between the storm door and entry door, but this low profile closer might solve that issue.

Comment: You are welcome. Here is a web page that leads you to the 2nd product "Wright Products V150WH Heavy Duty Pneumatic Closer", https://www.bing.com/search?q=Wright+Products+V150WH+Heavy+Duty+Pneumatic+Closer&cvid=c0dad2f04c6f463dad338846414a0516&aqs=edge..69i57j69i60.2918j0j9&FORM=ANAB01&PC=LCTS. Note there are many comparable products that you can check out yourself.

Answer (score 3):

There's no purpose built market solution for what you're after. I've installed a commercial closer to a residential storm door for this reason, Hager 5300 are pretty reasonably priced. However, if you're trying to eak out the last inch of clearance so you can get through the doorway, then the problem won't really be resolved until you're at about 135 degrees which a railing may obstruct because the back-face-corner of the door will still be swinging through the effective / "free and clear" opening width.

If you just want it to open further for a sense of space, then your looking to a commercial closer... the benefit of the hager and that class of closer is the lifetime warranty on replacement. All oil filled closers will leak, it's just a matter of when. Nice to have a free replacement as long as your going to tap a door so the next unit fits in same fastener location, and you'd just swap bodies so you can keep the arm and not have to redo more.